# Optimize Apache POI .xls file append

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls, hssf

Can someone please let me know if there is a memory efficient way to append to .xls files. (Client is very insistent on .xls file for the report and I did all possible research but in vain) All I could find is that to append to existing .xls, we first have to load the entire file into memory, append data and then write it back. Is that the only way ? I can afford to give up on time to optimize memory consumption.

Comment: How big are the files you're talking about?

Comment: Reports could be anywhere from 200 MB to 2 GB

Comment: There are mentions here regarding limitations when it comes to large files https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/limitations.html, there are suggestions for reading and writing files with streams although I can't help you with implementation since I've never used these.

Comment: Been through that doc already. Unfortunately all tutorials/guides just deal with optimizing read/write task. In my case I still have to hold all that data in-memory even if I read it efficiently.

Comment: Swap to `.xlsx` or `.csv`  ?

Comment: Client insists. Upstream where the report is sent needs `.xls`

Comment: So, is there no solution to this ?

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid that is not possible using `apache poi`. And I doubt that it will be possible by other libraries. Even the Microsoft applications itself needs always opening the whole file to be able to work with it.

All of the Microsoft Office file formats have a complex internal structure similar to a file system. And the parts of that internal system may have relations to each other. So one cannot simply stream data into those files and append data as it is possible with plain text files or CSV files or single XML files for example. One always needs considering the validity of the complete file system and its realtions. So the complete file system always needs to be known. And where should it be known when not in memory?

The modern Microsoft Office file formats are Office Open XML. This are ZIP archives containing an internal file system having a directory structure containing XML files and other files too. So one can reduce the memory footprint by reading data parts from that ZIP file system directly instead of reading all data into the memory by unzipping the ZIP file system. This is what `apache poi` tries with [XSSF and SAX (Event API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#xssf_sax_api). But this is for reading only.

For the writing approach one could have parts of the data (single XML files) written to temporary files to keep them away from the memory. Then put the complete ZIP file system together from those temporary files when all writing is complete. This is what [SXSSF (Streaming Usermodel API)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf) tries to do. But this is for writing only.

When it comes to appending data to an existing Microsoft Office file, then nothing of the above is useable. Because, as said already, one always needs considering the validity of the complete file system and its realtions. So the complete file system always needs to be known. So the whole file system always needs to be accessible to append data parts to it and update the relationships. One could think about having all data parts (single XML files) and relationship parts in temporary files to keep them away from the memory. But I don't know any library (maybe the closed source ones like Aspose) who does this. And I doubt that will be possible in a performant way. So you would pay time for a lower memory footprint.

The older Microsoft Office file formats are binary file systems but also consists in an complex internal structure. The single parts are streams of binary records which also may have relations to each other. So the main problem is the same as with Office Open XML.

There is [Event API (HSSF Only)](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#event_api) which tries **reading** single record streams similiar to the event API for Office Open XML. But, of course, this is for reading only.

There is no streaming approach for writing `HSSF` upto now. And the reason is that the old binary Excel worksheets only provide 65,536 rows and 256 columns. So the data amount in one sheet cannot be that big. So a GB sized `*.xls` file should not occur at all. You should not use Excel as data exchange format for database data. This is not what a spreadsheet calculation application is made for.

But even if one would program a streaming approach for writing `HSSF` this would not solve your problem. Because there is still nothing for appending data to an existing `*.xls` file. And the problems for this are the same as with the Office Open XML file formats.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to provide such insightful answer. Do you think the closed source library that you mentioned **Aspose** would be of help ? We are ready to use paid libraries.

Comment: @HeXMaN: Well, as it is closed source one cannot have a look at the code. But there is a free trial version (https://products.aspose.com/cells/java/). And as it is paid you should get contact to a sales person who can answer such questions.

Comment: understood thanks!